# ArrayList<? extends A> vs ArrayList<A>

Tags: java

Suppose I have:

```
class A{
}
class B extends A{
}
class C extends A{
}
```

Why and when we want to use `ArrayList<? extends A>`, Why not simply write `ArrayList<A>` ?

Comment: So why don't you create two lists and add A's and B's to it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you are not the one creating the List, you are getting it passed to you from somewhere.  Say you have a method that takes an argument `List<? extends A>`.  Someone could call your method and pass to you a `List<B>` that he created.  However, if you declared your argument to be just `List<A>`, he would not be allowed to pass his `List<B>` to you.

Here's why:  In the first case, where your argument is `List<? extends A>`, you are not allowed to add to this list because you don't know how the caller created it.  If you added, say, an instance of C and returned, he would now have a C object in his `List<B>`.  If it were a real `List<A>`, you'd be able to add to it safely.

Comment: Here's why: Because `List<A>` and `List<B>` are unrelated. [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/5221149)